# flutter and bloc asynchronous yield

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, yield, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using flutter with the BLoC pattern (with the flutter_bloc library) and I have these events:

`PersonalFileAddedEvent(File file), PersonalFileUploadEvent(PersonalFile file)` (both extend from `PersonalFileEvent`)

File is a file from the file picker, PersonalFile is a class that has these enum statuses: `READY_TO_UPLOAD, UPLOADING, UPLOAD_FINISHED`.

And this status from the BLoC:

`PersonalFileListLoadedState(List<PersonalFile> files)` (extend from `PersonalFileListState`)

When the user selects a file, the UI calls the event `PersonalFileAddedEvent` and passes it to the BLoC which creates a `PersonalFile` object and sets it's status to `READY_TO_UPLOAD`. This `PersonalFile` object gets 
added to a list which holds all the PersonalFile's that the user is adding (and uploading). The BLoC then responds (`yield`) with the `PersonalFileListLoadedState(blocPersonalFileList)` to the UI to render the information.

Once added, an "upload now" button gets rendered in the UI for that `PersonalFile`. When pressed, this calls the `PersonalFileUploadEvent` event and sends along the `PersonalFile` to the BLoC to start the upload process (multipart upload).
Immediately after receiving the event, the BLoC updates this PersonalFile's status to `UPLOADING` and `yield` the `PersonalFileListLoadedState` state with the PersonalFile's status updated for the UI to show that it is uploading.

The method that uploads the multipart file is async:

```
Future<PersonalFile> upload(PersonalFile file) async { //upload code }
```

This is the mapEventToState from flutter_bloc:

```
Stream<PersonalFileListState> mapEventToState(PersonalFileEvent event) async* {}
```

Inside this `mapEventToState` method I am awaiting the upload method to update the PersonalFile's status to `UPLOAD_FINISHED`.

The problem starts now, as the user adds several files from the file picker, and presses all the "upload" buttons. The BLoC gets blocked after receiving the first event and processes the events "synchronous like" and the UI
remains as if the other's PersonalFile's "upload" button were not pressed until the first one finishes (then the next one, and so on).

After one event gets fully processed (the upload completes), the next one gets processed, which makes sense since I am awaiting for the upload method to finish.

How can I write this code so that if the user presses several "upload" buttons in the UI, the BLoC does not get blocked (and thus the UI because the BLoC is unable to `yield` the new state) and all the files get uploaded
in parallel but only until each one finishes the BLoC sends the new `List` of `PersonalFile` with their status changed to `UPLOAD_FINISHED`?

I have tried changing the upload method's signature to:

```
Stream<PersonalFile> upload(PersonalFile file) async* { //upload code }
```

and using:

```
.then((file) { yield PersonalFileListLoadedState(listWithUpdatedPersonalFileStatus) })
```

but the code inside never gets executed. I tried debug but I cannot reach the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how are you calling the bloc to start the process upload.
But if you are using `bloc.add(event)` when the button is pressed it should be processed in an asyncronous way and yield the new statuses as needed.

Also notice that when you are processing the status change if the same state is yielded several times, the listener will listen to it only once so you wont see more than one update in your UI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that is correct, it works great adding a new event inside the bloc itself. Thank you very much!

Comment: @HollandSalazar How did you added the events inside bloc? can you please help me with some code?

Comment: for example, when you press the button, you add that event as `bloc.add(my_event)`, so in your bloc, inside the method to handle the event you can do something like:

`Stream<PrintJobsState> _addPrintJob(PrintJob job, StorageProvider provider, StorageFile file) async* {
    /// process your event.
    add(new_event);
   /// Continue processing your event
}
`